# Yarn install results in the error "Internal Error: Expected an indexed object, got a string instead. Does your file follow Yaml's rules?"

Tags: yarnpkg-v3

When trying to run the command `yarn install`, the following error message is displayed:

> "Internal Error: Expected an indexed object, got a string instead. Does your file follow Yaml's rules?"

My `.yarnrc.yml` is syntactically correct. What is the cause of the error?

- Yarn v3.2.2
- Node v16.14.0

[Related discussion at github.com/yarnpkg/](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/235)

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the `yarn.lock` file from the same folder and running `yarn install` afterward solved the issue.